# Insert Array of values into columns of the table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have an array

```
(1,2,3,4;5,6,7,8;9,10,11,12;13,14,15,16;)
```

I want to insert this array of values into the table like

```
Column1 |  Column2 | Column3 | Column4
-----------------------------------------
    1   |   2      |   3     |    4
    5   |   6      |   7     |    8
    9   |  10      |  11     |   12
   13   |  14      |  15     |   16
```

Comment: Are you asking this from a programming language point of view, or do you just want to conceptually add this data directly into SQL Server?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO TableName (Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4) 
VALUES (1,2,3,4),(5,6,7,8),(9,10,11,12),(13,14,15,16)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this "transposed"? I.e. provide all the values to go in each column, rather than each row? I ask because I already have large arrays for each column and seems dumb to loop through them all just to restructure the data in terms of rows.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @array varchar(max) = '(1,2,3,4;5,6,7,8;9,10,11,12;13,14,15,16;)'
SET @array = REPLACE( REPLACE(@array, ';', '), ('), ', ()', '')
DECLARE @SQLQuery VARCHAR(MAX) = 'INSERT INTO TABLENAME (Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4) VALUES ' + @array
EXEC (@SQLQuery)
```

Comment: I want to insert 1 in column1 ,2 in column2, 3 in column3, 4 in column4........... not like this

Comment: it does exactly the same. try it... @Vinod

Comment: i am geting like(1,2,3,4), (5,6,7,8), (9,10,11,12), (13,14,15,16) but i need 1 in column1 ,2 in column2, 3 in column3, 4 in column4...........

Comment: if youre running the exact code as above, youll get exact output as shown in your question.

Comment: this is what i executed -Select REPLACE( REPLACE('(1,2,3,4;5,6,7,8;9,10,11,12;13,14,15,16;)', ';', '), ('), ', ()', '') and i got (1,2,3,4), (5,6,7,8), (9,10,11,12), (13,14,15,16)

Comment: so you didnt run the exact query as above...
youre using just the select clause and hence youre getting that result. if you want to insert that data to a table, make the dynamic query and execute it....

Comment: Sorry i cant get you,I m getting what i need

Comment: THAT SCRIPT SHOULD BE USED IF YOU HAVE ALREADY CREATED A TABLE WITH ABOVE MENTIONED COLUMNS AND YOU WANT TO INSERT THOSE RECORDS AS YOU MENTIONED. IF ANYTHING ELSE, YOULL HAVE TO MODIFY THE QUERY ACCORDINGLY

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO TableName
VALUES 
(1,2,3,4),(5,6,7,8),(9,10,11,12),(13,14,15,16)
```